# Sort a dateTime list in C#

Tags: c#

I want to sort a list of strings which are formatted to be parsed to dateTime

for example :

```
19-06-2014
18-06-2014
17-06-2014
```

// all are strings

with this block of code :

```
var orderedList = newlist.OrderByDescending( x => DateTime.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

> this gives me the following exception : String was not recognized as a
>   valid DateTime.

As far as i know XX-XX-XXX is correct if you want to parse it to dateTime ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` as `dd-MM-yyyy` is not a standard date format in most Cultures (where it's usually `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`).

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> dtes =
    datesAsString.Select(
        str => DateTime.ParseExact( str, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture )
    ).
    OrderByDescending( dt = > dt );
```

Comment: Or `yyyy-MM-dd` for a machine-readable standard format...

Comment: @JonSkeet the OP didn't say he was responsible for the format of his strings, otherwise I'd have set to dump an int64 of unix time ;)

Comment: @Dai I think Jon's point is that `yyyy-mm-dd` is still human-readable and unambiguous because no cultures use a `yyyy-dd-mm` format.